# Delineate new political boundary in dataset

Tags: qgis

In the political area I'm working on, there has been a recent formation of a new city, legitimized with government plebiscites and resolutions etc.

Geographically speaking, it's still the same land area (original town), but split into two new towns. There are no "new" extents since the New Town follows the lines of the subtowns that make it up.

To summarize:

```
Original Town (All Subtowns) = Town 1 (Subtowns group 1) + New Town (Subtowns group 2).
```

**More information:**
Towns.shp and Subtowns.shp are separate datasets. The particular information in Subtowns.shp are not present in Towns.shp, and both are present in our country GIS website separately, for convenience.

**What I want to do:**
Create the New Town boundary in Towns.shp using the boundaries of the edge-lying subtowns that make it up, but however are in Subtowns.shp.

Hope someone can help!

Comment: If I understand what you want to do, there are a number of ways to approach the problem. The simplest is probably to edit the towns.shp file and use the Cut Polygon tool to split the exiting town by tracing the correct boundaries in the subtowns.shp. Alternatively you could select the two subtown sets, export them to a new file, merge/dissolve the two groups to a single shape/feature, then replace the existing towns feature with those two new ones.

Comment: Your latter suggestion seems the best way. Lemme try it!